# How to write a generic Web API function which can call any stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to write a Controller in .NET CORE 2.1 (C#) which exposes a *SINGLE* function which can be used to call any stored procedure in sql server.

So this function must be able to take a list of undefined parameters, and it must be able to return the dataset the stored procedure is creating.

Is this possible? I'm new to Web API. I am practised in SQL Server and Windows Clients, but I am new to Web API and C# backends in general.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You probably don't actually... Seems to create a number of security issues. Sounds like you may want to look into SSRS

Comment: @Milney So you suggest to drop this idea and rather write a bunch of web api functions for each stored procedure?

Comment: Well what are you actually trying to accomplish? I'm just struggling to think of a set of requirements that that would be a good solution for

Comment: I've heard that Oracle APEX has a similar way. They have only one single function which delegates all calls to the database.

Comment: I have an existing database and an existing Windows Client which communicates only via stored procedures. Now we want to put a web api between sql server and Client.

Comment: My first try would be receive a JsonObject and than try to deserialize into a object until it works. But I have no idea if it will works. Another solution you could create an object for your request parameters, with one enum to identify the type and one property for each object you can receive, you just need to ensure the frontend will send the same format.

Comment: @askolotl what you ask is already available through OData or GraphQL. OData server libraries are available for all .NET stacks. GraphQL is supported through third-party packages and far more popular

Comment: @askolotl in any case APEX is a RAD tool similar to the old Oracle Forms, not a database access API. I'd bet it *doesn't* use a single function to call all stored procedures either. Most likely it uses an OData-like API for data communication between the browser app and the server-side services

Answer (score 3):

as with every big problem, think about splitting it up.
you want a single method which can execute any stored procedure.

what do you need to execute a stored procedure?

1. its name
2. list of parameter names, types and values
3. finally, you need to return unspecified data.

So, find a way to pass that data through, then find a way to convert all that data into something that your stored procedure accepts, this depends on what you are using to call it, is it straight ADo.Net, is it Dapper, is it EF etc.

is it possible? yes, of course as long as you find a way of doing these things.

Start simple, first a stored procedure with no input parameters.
Get that working then move on to a stored procedure with one param and see how that goes.

Your first model could look like this:

```
public class InputModel  
{
     public string StoredProcedureName {get;set;}     

     public List<StoredProcedureParameter> StoredProcedureParameters
}
```

then add the params part:

```
public class StoredProcedureParameter 
{
    public string Name { get;set; }  
    public TypeEnum ParamType { get; set }
    public string Value { get;set; }
}
```

This is an example of how I would approach it.

Now that I have my inputs, I just need to convert from these to whatever is used to 
execute the sp.

Once you manage to execute the sp, then you can decide how you're going to return the data. You can use the `dynamic` data type for that and the API will serialise it to JSON so you should have no issues there.

One small step at a time basically. It can be done and I have done something similar in the past.